# Unable to disable assignment rules

Tags: apex, trigger, assignment-rules

I have a condition where I need to disable standard `Lead Assignment Rules` if certain criteria are met.

```
if(emailWithAccIdMap.containsKey(ledRec.Email) && emailWithAccIdMap.get(ledRec.Email) != null && !openOppMap.isEmpty() && openOppMap.get(emailWithAccIdMap.get(ledRec.Email)) != null && openOppMap.get(emailWithAccIdMap.get(ledRec.Email)).Owner.isActive ==true){
                    ledRec.Status = 'Duplicate';
                    System.debug('Changing the Status');
                    //then assign the original lead owner to new lead owner
                    ledRec.OwnerId = openOppMap.get(emailWithAccIdMap.get(ledRec.Email)).OwnerId;
                    ledRec.Account_Name__c = openOppMap.get(emailWithAccIdMap.get(ledRec.Email)).AccountId;
                    ledRec.Field_for_Lead_Workflow__c = true;
                    Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
                    dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = false;
                    ledRec.setOptions(dmo);
                    //since owner is assigned, it shouledRec not pass through round robin
                    ledRec.checkAssignment__c = false; 
}
```

This is my code snippet which is running on `before insert`. The control is entering the `IF` condition as the debug statement is getting printed. Yet, the owner assigned through this snippet is being overridden by the assignment rules.

I also tried executing this in `after insert` trigger context but it did not work. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = false` will not stop you firing the rule.

Refer [DmlOptions.AssignmentRuleHeader Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_AssignmentRuleHeader.htm)

> DmlOptions.AssignmentRuleHeader Properties

- assignmentRuleID: Specifies the ID of a specific assignment rule to run for the case or lead. The assignment rule can be active or inactive.
- useDefaultRule: If specified as true for a case or lead, the system uses the default (active) assignment rule for the case or lead. If specified, do not specify an assignmentRuleId.

Best way, to handle this situation is to create a `Boolean` field like `stopAssignmentRule` and make it `true` during before insert trigger.

Use this `stopAssignmentRule` field in the assignment rule entries where you want to satisfy assignment or not.

So, if no assignments are satisfied then the record will be assigned to Default Owner as defined in Lead Settings.

Now, you need to change the ownership through a trigger. So, create an after trigger which will assign the correct owner based on your code logic.

Hope it makes sense!!

Comment: This answer is your best option user2529.
@santanu-boral, I'm not sure if this paragraph make sense:
"Now, you need to change the ownership through a trigger. So, **create an after trigger** which will assign the correct owner based on your code logic."
You cannot change the field value in after trigger. I believe the creation of stopAssigmentRule field and the properly change on Assigment Rule would be enough to solve the problem.
What do you think?

Comment: Actually, in the after trigger, Record is readonly, so to update those records, you may need to perform separate SOQL query or create a new instance of the object and perform the insert. there are several answers I have provided how you can update a record in `after trigger`. Thanks

Comment: So what is the use of dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = false?  Because if I have 150 existing assignment rules, I can't really go and change all of them. Isn't there any standard approach which will skip the assignment rules?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are setting `dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule` to false. So it might take the active assignment rule on lead and update it's owner. So remove the code for lead assignment rules

```
if(emailWithAccIdMap.containsKey(ledRec.Email) && emailWithAccIdMap.get(ledRec.Email) != null && !openOppMap.isEmpty() && openOppMap.get(emailWithAccIdMap.get(ledRec.Email)) != null && openOppMap.get(emailWithAccIdMap.get(ledRec.Email)).Owner.isActive ==true){
    ledRec.Status = 'Duplicate';
    System.debug('Changing the Status');
    //then assign the original lead owner to new lead owner
    ledRec.OwnerId = openOppMap.get(emailWithAccIdMap.get(ledRec.Email)).OwnerId;
    ledRec.Account_Name__c = openOppMap.get(emailWithAccIdMap.get(ledRec.Email)).AccountId;
    ledRec.Field_for_Lead_Workflow__c = true;
    //since owner is assigned, it shouledRec not pass through round robin
    ledRec.checkAssignment__c = false; 
}
```

Comment: But my code is on before insert trigger. Will the active assignment rules not fire anyway? dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = false will make it skip the assignment rules if I'm not wrong

Comment: I'm looking to disable the active assignment rules here

Comment: Assignment rules fires after trigger completion see here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm
so on your assignment rule that boolean need to be checked to proceed or skip assignment rule

Answer (score 0):

Setting DMLOption will execute Assignment Rule. If you don't want to run assignment rule in some criteria then do not set this option by using if check:

```
 if(emailWithAccIdMap.containsKey(ledRec.Email) && emailWithAccIdMap.get(ledRec.Email) != null && !openOppMap.isEmpty() && openOppMap.get(emailWithAccIdMap.get(ledRec.Email)) != null && openOppMap.get(emailWithAccIdMap.get(ledRec.Email)).Owner.isActive ==true){
                    ledRec.Status = 'Duplicate';
                    System.debug('Changing the Status');
                    //then assign the original lead owner to new lead owner
                    ledRec.OwnerId = openOppMap.get(emailWithAccIdMap.get(ledRec.Email)).OwnerId;
                    ledRec.Account_Name__c = openOppMap.get(emailWithAccIdMap.get(ledRec.Email)).AccountId;
                    ledRec.Field_for_Lead_Workflow__c = true;
                    **if(CRIETRAMETTORUNASSIGNMENTRULE){**
                        Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
                        dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = false;
                        ledRec.setOptions(dmo);
                    **}**
                    //since owner is assigned, it shouledRec not pass through round robin
                    ledRec.checkAssignment__c = false; 
}
```