# Turn off Case Assignment rules

Tags: apex, assignment-rules

I am trying to turn OFF case assignment rules on before case update. However, it seems they are still firing on any field update and assigning the owner to some default user.

Trigger:

```
trigger TurnOffAssignmentRule on Case (before update) { 
    List<ID> caseIDs = new List<ID>(); 

    for (Case c : Trigger.New){     
    caseIDs.add(c.Id);     
    } 

    if(caseIDs.size() > 0) { 
    CaseHelper.updateOwnership(caseIDs); 
    } 
}
```

Class:

```
public class CaseHelper { 
    public static void updateOwnership(List<Id> caseIDs) { 
        Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions(); 
        dmo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = false; 
        dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = false;
        List<Case> casesToUpdate = [select id from case where id in :caseIDs]; 

        Database.update(casesToUpdate, dmo);
    } 
}
```

I am not sure am taking right approach. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't intercept the assignment rules in a trigger, because the DML options have already been set for the current transaction. If you need to change ownership, do so later in a future method.

Comment: I have given an approach to that same type of question earlier here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185354/unable-to-disable-assignment-rules

Comment: Since I have less complex rules, I can go with Process buidler right? @SantanuBoral, yes, I actually did half of your solution that creating a custom field and use it assignment rule. Do you foresee any issue with Process builder? I dont have any triggers and complex logic on Case as of today.

Comment: @Ajay Process Builder runs after assignment rules, so you should be okay.